# Watchdog for Messaging Bus

Tags: java, plsql, watchdog, tibco-rv, message-bus

So I started to work in a semiconductor company as a working student and they gave me the task to write a watchdog for the tibco messaging bus. It should show the workload of the messaging bus, if it is busy at the moment or not.
I havent figured out everything yet, but as far as I understand the architecture now there are java processes like EQC and EQS who handle the messaging and interact with the messaging bus. We also have some servieces, that connect with the database. We have one big database with really big data. And we acces these data via pl/sql. 
So I have no clue how to start something like this. Do you guys have any idea how to start/ do this?

Comment: You may get further by inquiring your supervisor or another coworker rather than Stack Overflow with a question as broad as this.

Comment: Yes thats what I will do, but my supervisor said, that I should make thoughts about how I would do it and I thought, maybe someone in here would have an idea on how to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats one the new page of your life! Here, and specifically, on your case, we can share the tips and experience, to help you a bit. Of course, be prepared to do the heavy load yourself - that's the main point of learning. Tips:

- No one was borne all-knowing - ASK, and ask often. Give questions, even if it sounds funny/stupid;
- Fail fast and fail often - the goal is to do the task by using all the resources given (colleagues are resources too). If you can't come with a solution within 1-2 hours, ASK for help. Don't be afraid. Remember - failing is part of learning;
- If the task seems scary,big,too broad (like yours now) - dived them in to smaller peaces/steps, until every step is clear and understandable;
- Study other code - try to understand WHY its done the way it is. It's also a good topic with colleagues while drinking coffee (or smoking).

Supervisor wants to see how you cope with this huge task, but with YOUR strength. Take a paper and a pen, and try to create some sort of a workflow. Write every questions,that pops up. After this, you can go to your supervisor and discuss the current state, what needs to be done. If he is a good supervisor, he also will give you some hints/provide guidance.

If you stumble a technical issue, ask us - we will surely help you.

Good luck, mate!